# Is there a way to Inject and Execute C# application inside another process?

Tags: c#

I want to run my application under the app domain of another application, So for example `Windows Explorer` i can Initialize CLR into it, how can i run a .net application inside it after?, in another words how to host my .net application inside another running .net application or CLR activated process.

Comment: Sounds like hacking. There was a win32 weakness some many years ago by using the CreateRemoteThread API. I am doubt that this weakness is still present

Comment: @GeorgeLica for studying project.... still didn't get the point... i know CreateRemoteThread but how can i execute the entry point of the loaded assembly

Answer (score 1):

You can create a win32 exe in wich you define a method Starter that starts clr and starts your assembly. Next, you can inject that win32 exe in another process by using CreateRemoteThread and giving as the thread procedure a pointer to yout Starter method. But i am suuuure that any antivirus will scream or that windows itself will not allow you to do it